# Looping background in cocos2d iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, background, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing my first cocos2d game. It will have a looping background, three different layers that all loop at different speeds. The speed of the looping will change based on user input.

Here is how I am doing so

```
-(void) update: (ccTime) dt
{
for (CCSprite *bckgrnd in backgroundArray){
    switch (bckgrnd.tag) {
        case 0:
            bckgrnd.position = ccp(bckgrnd.position.x - speed * .30, bckgrnd.position.y);
            break;
        case 1:
            bckgrnd.position = ccp(bckgrnd.position.x - speed * .80, bckgrnd.position.y);
            break;
        case 2:
            bckgrnd.position = ccp(bckgrnd.position.x - speed * .50, bckgrnd.position.y);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    if (bckgrnd.position.x <= -kBacWidth) {
        CGPoint greatestPosition = CGPointMake(0, 0);
        for (CCSprite *sprt in backgroundArray){
            if (sprt.tag == bckgrnd.tag && sprt.position.x > greatestPosition.x) {
                greatestPosition = CGPointMake(sprt.position.x, sprt.position.y);
            }
        }

        bckgrnd.position = ccp(greatestPosition.x + kBacWidth, bckgrnd.position.y); 
    }
}
}
```

This works, but has two problems. First it creates a gap after the second time it loops, then the gap stays there. The other problem is the different pieces of the background seem to "wiggle" as they move left across the screen. This causes the separate sprites to over lap by maybe a pixel at times. Which I can not have. Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have the second for loop?  Isn't the sprt that passes the condition "sprt.tag == bckgrnd.tag" the same as bckgrnd... which you have already?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a ParallaxBackground for a vertical scrolling shooter game and here is my update method. I hope it does help to inspire yours as I also had the gap problem at the beginning..

Te speedFactors is an array of float objects which determines the speed of each stripe of the background. I multiply numStripes by 2 as I have a top and bottom stripe (image divided in halves) so I can reposition them when they go out from the visual range (condition: **if(pos.y < -screenSize.height)**).

The sprites are added as childs to the class but you could use a CCSpriteBatch as well if you like or your backgroundArray as well.

```
-(void) update:(ccTime)delta
{
    CCSprite* sprite;
    int factorIndex=0;
    for (int i=0; i<(numStripes*2); i++) {

        sprite = (CCSprite*)[self getChildByTag:firstParallaxSpriteTag+i];

        NSNumber* factor = [speedFactors objectAtIndex:factorIndex];

        CGPoint pos = sprite.position;
        pos.y -= scrollSpeed * [factor floatValue];;

        // Reposition stripes when they're out of bounds
        if (pos.y < -screenSize.height)
        {
            pos.y += (screenSize.height * 2) - 2;
        }
        sprite.position = pos;   
        factorIndex++;
        if(factorIndex>=numStripes){
            factorIndex=0;
        }
    }   
}
```

Hope that this help, please do not hesitate asking further question via comments.

PS: For the record, my method and class are modifications of the ParallaxBackground class from the ShootEmUp example in [this book](http://www.apress.com/9781430233039/). You can find the source code in the link and I suggest you buy the book as well.

PPS: To avoid a gap of 1 pixel you need to remove it when repositioning the sprite, to avoid a gap of a background sprite you need to allocate two instances of the background sprite and alternate them in the screen (when one is out from the visual range you reposition it at the beginning -top or side of the screen, in your case side-) and then you keep moving both background sprites.. if you see my code or even more the PrallaxBackground example in the book you will understand.